# hibernate when merging object sets field to null

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, merge

I have a class that goes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTIONS")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TX_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_COST")
    private Double amountCost;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_TAX")
    private Double amountTax;


@NotNull
@Column(name = "BANKACCOUNT")
private String bankAccount;

//getters and setters here
    }
```

the problem is, when I create Transaction object, and fill data, and then I want it to merge, hibernate merges it with fields AMOUNT_COST and BANKACCOUNT set to null. I checked with debugger - the object I want to merge is correctly filled with data, AMOUNT_COST is set to 0.0 and BANKACCOUNT is correct.

I have no clue what might be the problem here:
-I double checked column names
-I double checked my sql table, and types of data
-I tried to put annotations on getters, or on declaration of variable - nothing changes.

When I set columns to 'nullable' then the object is merged with null values, but only for those two fields (!). I'm clueless here, so I really need a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ha. I forgot to mention that I'm using extended entity menager, and in this case, it was it's fault.